# How can I patch a system library in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to make a very minor patch to a file of the Android Core but even though I'm pretty well-versed with writing Android applications, I'm quite lost with how to go about this.

The line of the file I'm trying to patch is here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/CallLog.java#L357

I'd like modify the code so that it is never invoked. (Just imagine it being commented out.)

How should I go about this? Is it possible to create a patch for this? My last resort would be to use the Xposed Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method for accomplishing this in clean way seems to be using the Xposed Framework: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401

Answer (score 4):

You cannot alter internal parts of the framework simply by installing an apk or something.

You will require root at a minimum, and even then I doubt you can make this kind of change.

The only way I can think of to do this would be to change the line in Android's source, build a ROM image and flash that onto your device, like you would with Cyanogen and other custom flavors of Android.

Comment: I kind of figured that would be the case (but didn't Facebook patch the dalvikvm for their new app?). I think I'll use the Xposed Framework and give it a shot.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla They didn't exactly patch it. They used the NDK to catch hold of the dalvik VM's object and increase its memory buffer. What you're trying to do is comment out an exiting line of code from already compiled and deployed Java code. AFAIK this isn't possible without a custom ROM.